# Log exception source from flask decorator

Tags: exception, flask, python-3.6

I'm using a python decorator to handle exceptions in my flask app.

**decorators.py**

```
def exception(original_function=None, message='Some error occurred on our end.', app=None):
    def decorator(function):
        @functools.wraps(function)
        def wrapper_function(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return function(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                handler(app, e)
                return internal_error(message)

        return wrapper_function
```

The `handler` function captures the exception details and logs or displays them.

```
def handler(app, e='Exception'):
    exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    exc_type, filename, line_no = exc_type, exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename, exc_tb.tb_lineno

    app.logger.error(f'\n+{"-" * 64}\n'
                     '| Exception details:\n'
                     f'| Message: {e}\n'
                     f'| Type:\t\t{exc_type}\n'
                     f'| File:\t\t{filename}\n'
                     f'| Line No:\t\t{line_no}\n'
                     f'+{"-" * 64}\n')
```

Then I use it in flask routes as:

**route.py**

```
@bp.route('/initialize/<string:uuid>/<string:method>', methods=['POST'])
@exception(app=current_app)
def initialize(uuid=None, method=None):
    if not uuid:
        return bad_request('No UUID')
```

Right now, the handler does work, however, it logs that the exception originated from decorators.py on the `return function(*args, **kwargs)` line. **How can I log the actual file and line the exception originated?**

Here is an output of the log.

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------
| Exception details:
| Message: Required PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID and PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET.    
| Type:         <class 'paypalrestsdk.exceptions.MissingConfig'>
| File:         /app/decorators.py
| Line No:              16
+----------------------------------------------------------------
```